# Jersey response HTTP 400 Bad Requests, no clue way

Tags: java, tomcat, nginx, jersey, http-status-code-400

I have an NGINX server, then a Tomcat as Servlet Container. 
I upgrade from jersey 2.25.1 to 2.26 and I could make it work:

I updated the Java version in the server from jdk1.8.0_91 to jdk1.8.0_161.
I updated dependencies in my REST project:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <!-- Jersey core Servlet 2.x implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <scope>${dependency.scopes}</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <scope>${dependency.scopes}</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        <scope>${dependency.scopes}</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jersey Multipart entity providers support module -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <scope>${dependency.scopes}</scope>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <scope>${dependency.scopes}</scope>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-base</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Where dependency.scopes is provided. All dependencies are placed inside lib folder of Tomcat. I had some issues regarding dependencies, but now I don't see exceptions about that.

NGINX redirects HTTP and HTTPS backends traffic to Tomcat. When I request using HTTP, I get the right response. When I request using HTTPS I don't, I get HTTP 400. Same URL, same request headers, just changing the protocol.

Also, if I request the same URL using WGET command from the NGINX server, I get the right answer from Tomcat (with HTTP and with HTTPS).

So, Tomcat looks like is answering well in both protocols, but sometimes.

There isn't any exception in any log in the tomcat. I just see the HTTP 400 code in the access log, when I request the GET, through NGINX.

```
  HTTPS Request
  - - - [02/Apr/2018:17:02:00 +0000] "GET /request HTTP/1.0" 400 1001 71 https-jsse-nio-8542-exec-4

  HTTP Request
  - - - [02/Apr/2018:17:29:35 +0000] "GET /request HTTP/1.0" 200 45 16 https-jsse-nio-8542-exec-9
```

It looks like the problem is produced in the HTTP headers, but I can't see them from tomcat side. It's possible to enable some extra logging to get any clue?

Thanks,

The following image shows the dependencies added in tomcat:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem in the NGINX configuration, comparing HTTP and HTTPS configurations. 
I had wrong HOST header.